# Data extract, report generation automation in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, amazon-athena, data-extraction

I have an Adhoc monthly task to extract a set of reports from the database, do some data manipulation in excel, and share it to different teams by mail. I'm currently doing it manually.

I'm looking to automate it with AWS Serverless services.
I looked at lambda(+S3+SES), but lambda has a timeout limit of 15 minutes (this data extraction takes 20-40 minutes).

I've explored AWSGlue(+S3+SES) for extraction and manipulation. But I'm concerned about the learning curve and time involved in development with PySpark.
Because the database is not my core skill although I can do some basic coding with python.

Is there any other AWS service/Stack which I could consider to automate it?
Any lead/direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Use ECS to run Docker container instead of lambda if you need more time.

Comment: You don't have to use PySpark if you're not working with a large enough dataset that needs distributed processing. It can be just a Python script executed within the Glue execution environment - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html